# How to get sum of rows based on certain conditions for a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, sum

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | 10 |
| z | t | 20 |
| y | o | 30 |
| t | z | 5 |
| y | x | 100 |

If the above table is my initial pandas dataframe, I want my final one to look like the one below

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | 110 |
| z | t | 25 |
| y | o | 30 |

I have currently tried iterating over the entire dataframe, row wise and swapping column values wherever required and finally getting the sum, but this did not give the required output and it was time consuming.

Comment: df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()